# c# how to write the code for: if data from database is the same as the data that was put in, do this

Tags: c#, database

So I have created this command to retrieve data from my database, the question now is how do I write the code that if the data that was put in is the same as the data in the database, it closes this form and opens a new one.

```
SqlDataAdapter command = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from tblLogin where Gebruikersnaam = @Gebruiker and GeheimeVraag = @GeheimeVraag and Antwoord = @Antwoord", con);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        command.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gebruiker", txtGebruikersnaam.Text);
        command.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GeheimeVraag", ddlGeheimeVraag.Text);
        command.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Antwoord", txtAntwoord.Text);
        command.Fill(dt);

        if ()
        {
            this.Hide();
            FormLoginWW2 ss = new FormLoginWW2();
            ss.Show();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error");
        }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "if data is correct"? How would you judge this?

Comment: if the same data that was put in is the same as the data in the database. Made an edit to the question in the hopes that it would be more clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [query and return a scalar value](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar(v=vs.110).aspx), and evaluate that:

SqlData

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("select 1 from tblLogin where Gebruikersnaam = @Gebruiker and GeheimeVraag = @GeheimeVraag and Antwoord = @Antwoord", con);
        command.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gebruiker", txtGebruikersnaam.Text);
        command.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GeheimeVraag", ddlGeheimeVraag.Text);
        command.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Antwoord", txtAntwoord.Text);

var value = command.ExecuteScalar();

if (Object.Equals(value, 1))
{
   //Success
}
else
{
   //Failure
}
```

The value of '1' will probably be evaluated as int, not bool, so you can cast in the query if you wanted it to expect a bool...  If it's not 1, meaning no results returned, `DBNull.Value' is returned instead.

Comment: strange it gives me this error https://gyazo.com/d8c600f17c92630051fb664fa97283f4 edit: ah if where to change sqldataadapter to just adapter what namespace reference do I need to add exactly?

Comment: Sorry, changed to SQLCommand; you don't need the adapter - just use a command for that.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your query is looking up for a particular row in db table and if it exists you do something. You can do below

```
if(dt!=null)
{
  if(dt.Rows.Count>0)
  {
    //do your code 
  }
}
```

**Update:**

One approach is as explained by [Brian Mains](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37513368/2196341)

Another way of doing this would be like I explained. You can change you query to return first record(I'm assuming it will always be one record, since its a login)

```
 SqlDataAdapter command = new SqlDataAdapter("select TOP 1 * from tblLogin where Gebruikersnaam = @Gebruiker and GeheimeVraag = @GeheimeVraag and Antwoord = @Antwoord", con);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        command.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gebruiker", txtGebruikersnaam.Text);
        command.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GeheimeVraag", ddlGeheimeVraag.Text);
        command.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Antwoord", txtAntwoord.Text);
        command.Fill(dt);



 if(dt!=null)
    {
      if(dt.Rows.Count>0)
       {
                this.Hide();
                FormLoginWW2 ss = new FormLoginWW2();
                ss.Show();
            }
     else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error");
            }
    }
```

Comment: No, I want to check if the data that I put in my textboxes is the same as the data in the database. Think of it like in a login system

Comment: Hey thank you for taking your time for answering my question, sadly i will chose the one above for my best answer because I think the var value = command.ExecuteScalar(); will be very usefull for in the future. However I will definetly use your method aswell when using a datatable. I hope you won't be mad that I didn't chose you as best answer :/ Thank you again for answering!

Comment: No worries. I agree. I personally feel that's the better approach, I just wanted to add an alternative.

Comment: Hey would you perhaps be able to help me out with a follow up on this question? You seems to be a very good programmer. I programmed most of what I need myself but I just don't know how to do one more thing. I will post a link to the question in another comment once I have completed my waiting time. I know it sounds a bit rude to ask for your help like this, but I thought since you already have an understanding of my program that I might aswell try. I hope you don't mind doing this :/

Comment: Sure, post the link. I'll take a look when i get some free time

Comment: here you go, hope you can help out :/ I also translated so it becomes easyer to understand http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37514210/c-sharp-send-values-that-were-selected-from-a-database-from-one-form-to-another