# c# Send values that were selected from a database from one form to another form

Tags: c#, database, forms, select

So in form1 I select data from my database and if that data is the same as the data that I typed inside the textboxes then it closes the form and opens a new one.

```
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("select 1 from tblLogin where Username = @user and Securityquestion = @securityquestion and Answer = @answer", con);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user", txtUsername.Text);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@securityqestion", ddlSecurityquestions.Text);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@answer", txtAnswer.Text);

        var value = command.ExecuteScalar();
        con.Close();

        if (Object.Equals(value, 1))
        {
            this.Hide();
            FormLoginWW2 ss = new FormLoginWW2();
            ss.Show();

        FormLoginWW2 objForm2 = new FormLoginWW2();
        objForm2.ShowDialog();
        string ret = objForm2.ReturnedText;
        objForm2.ReturnedText = txtUsername.Text;
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error");
        }
```

This is form2. So what I want is that the username that I entered in form1 is shown inside a label so that I can then change the password of that username inside the database.

```
        public string ReturnedText = "";


        ReturnedText = labelUsername.Text;
        SqlCommand command;
        command = new SqlCommand("select * from tblLogin where Username = @user", con);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user", labelUsername.Text);

        if (txtPassword.Text == txtConfirmpassword.Text)
        {

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("update tblLogin SET Password = @password where Username = @user ", con);

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", txtPassword.Text);

            MessageBox.Show("Success");

            this.Hide();
            FormLogin ss = new FormLogin();
            ss.Show();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error.");
        }
```

Comment: You can try to pass through parameters, `public void Form1(string Username)`

Comment: So you already have the user name? I dont understand what you want to do. Do you want to replace `THEUSERNAMEFROMFORM1 ` with actual username? if yes, then use value from label

Comment: I just don't know how to use the pass value in this case

Comment: I edited how I tried to do it

Answer (score 0):

in form1

```
    public string txtsturen
    {
        get { return txtGebruikersnaam.Text; }
    }
```

//this in button

```
            FormLoginWW2 frm = new FormLoginWW2();
            frm.txtsturen = txtsturen;
            frm.Show();
            this.Close();
```

in form2

```
    public string txtsturen
    {
        set { labelGebruikersnaam.Text = value; }
    }
```